# Is there a way to make the Shadow Blade spell into a warlock pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

The [*shadow blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shadow-blade) spell (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 164) states:

> You weave together threads of shadow to create a sword of solidified gloom in your hand. This magic sword lasts until the spell ends. It counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient. It deals 2d8 psychic damage on a hit and has the finesse, light, and thrown properties (range 20/60).

**Is there a way to make a *shadow blade* into a pact weapon** for a [Pact of the Blade warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#PactBoon)? Or can I use an [Eldritch Invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations) to make it so?

Comment: Please don't share the full text of spells found outside free material. If they have the book users can look it up themselves.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is an official rule to make this happen? Or are you asking if it would be balanced to do so? (Or something else?)

Comment: @ Gandalfmeansme: Well since pointed that out...both

Comment: Related: [Can the Shadow Blade spell qualify as the Warlock's summoned Pact of the Blade weapon (& the Hex Warrior feature)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143406/can-the-shadow-blade-spell-qualify-as-the-warlocks-summoned-pact-of-the-blade-w)

Answer (score 17):

## The Shadow Blade doesn't exist long enough.

The duration of *shadow blade* is 1 minute (concentration). Pact of the Blade (PHB. 108, emphasis mine) states:

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon [...] over the course of **1 hour**, which can be done during a short rest.

Even assuming the ritual does not take concentration or you would have some way to circumvent it if it did, the *shadow blade* does not exist long enough to finish the ritual required to bind it.

Comment: You beat me by seconds! Also I added in a section of the quote "while you hold the weapon" because without it there could be an argument about just summoning the sword at the end of the ritual or something.

Comment: Side note, While a Shadow Blade is not eligible for a Pact Weapon, a Hexblade warlock can still imbue it with its Hex Warrior benefit.

Comment: Ok....what about using up an Invocation slot to have as an at will spell and doesn't count to number of spells known?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver There is not one that exists to do what you're describing.  However, look up the Curse Bringer invocation in Unearthed Arcana.  It is very similar to what you're looking for .

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver: This is a different question then what you asked above. Feel free to put it in a new question so we can answer it!

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver There are many Invocations that grant you at-will spells that don't count against your spells known number. Eldritch Sight is one, for example, but casting a second level spell like *shadow blade* is a minimum level 9 invocation, probably level 15 (see Ascendant Step and Master of Myriad Forms), and even then most of the Invocation spells are not combat defining spells.

Answer (score -2):

Work with your DM to craft a magic weapon that has these properties. If you know the spell, and can figure out how to attach the spell to a weapon, you can then use your Pact of the Blade to summon your new magic weapon.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE Eric.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how a Q&A site is not the same as a discussion forum.  Have you done this, and come up with a time, cost, and rarity for such a blade (per the DMG magic item creation section)?  If not, then the "[back it up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/627/22566)" requirement to support an answer to a question like this is missing.  If you have  made an item like this, then explaining the process/reasoning of how you came up with it in more detail would make for a good answer.

Answer (score -4):

Do not forget that dipping in to a 3rd level sorceror can supply you with the metamagic of extended spell, which means you can extend the duration of shadow blade to 24 hours which is more than enough time to preform the binding ritual, so with enough patience and a sorcerorlock combo, it is possible, whether this would use spell slots or not when you cast it, is more likely than not leaning towards no, as it would cast it from your patrons magic rather than your own, but I'd recommend asking your DM. (I would consider it a form of mastery of the spell, such as signature spells and mystic arcanums)

Comment: That would let you extend the duration to 2 minutes, not to an hour.

Comment: What Miniman said. The Extended Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) option says: "When you cast a spell that has a duration of 1 minute or longer, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double its duration, to a maximum duration of 24 hours." 24 hours is just the maximum possible duration; relatively few spells even have a duration of 12 hours, which is the minimum spell duration needed for that upper limit of Extended Spell to be relevant. Any shorter duration would merely be doubled by Extended Spell, not increased to 24 hours.