# Can the Shadow Blade spell qualify as the Warlock's summoned Pact of the Blade weapon (& the Hex Warrior feature)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock, hexblade

The reason I bring up the question is there has been some interesting tweets by Jeremy Crawford that seems to possibly open the door for this interaction.

**Jeremy Crawford (Lead D&D Rules Designer) stated this via twitter:**

> The Hex Warrior feature is intentionally worded to extend its benefit to two potential weapons: the weapon you touch and a pact weapon you conjure.

**More Jeremy Crawford:**

> When we wrote "every pact weapon" in Hex Warrior, we really meant every pact weapon. #DnD

**As a reminder The Pact of the Blade feature states thus:**

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand.

So, my question is can the Shadow Blade weapon you conjure be used as your pact weapon and thus benefit from Hex Warrior (or is the Shadow Blade spell dead weight for a Hexblade)?

Comment: Food for thought on the level of credence given to Jeremy Crawford's tweets: [With the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium release, are Jeremy Crawford's tweets considered to be “official rulings”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/41726) In fact, Crawford himself [has stated recently](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1105277917582389248) that his tweets are no longer official rulings. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate [Is there a way to make the shadow blade spell into a warlock pact weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127766/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-shadow-blade-spell-into-a-warlock-pact-weapon)

Comment: It is similar for sure, but I was trying to be specific about the Pact of the Blade summoning/Shadow Blade interaction along with the new information brought forth by Jeremy Crawford. I apologize if I was mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

## No to the Pact of the Blade feature.

The Warlock Pact of the Blade feature has two parts: you can create a pact weapon in your hand, or you can make a magic weapon into your pact weapon.

For creating a weapon:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it.

You can have your pact weapon take the form of a *Shadow Blade* (say, a long sword or rapier), but it's not magical in any way other than that described by the feature (such as being able to overcome resistance to non-magical weapons).

For making a magic weapon into a pact weapon:

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a short rest.

*Shadow Blade* lasts 1 minute, so there is no way that the ritual would complete in time.

## Yes to the Hexblade feature.

The Hexblade feature states:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls.

The *Shadow Blade*, as per the spell description, is a weapon you are proficient in that lacks the two-handed property.

However, as per the feature, you would have to do this immediately upon completing a long rest, and then it would last for the minute that the *Shadow Blade* existed.